# Why the tkinter widget appears on incorrect window?

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, treeview, ttk

I've been struggling for weeks with this bug. The menu is expected to open a new window based on the clicked button and so it does. The issue arises when a ttk.Treview object (or a table) is expected to show up in the new window but it keeps appearing on the menu one.
I've tried checking the parent-children relations, but all seems fine. Could someone please tell me why this keeps happenning?

```
from tkinter import * 
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

import sqlite3
from basicCRUD_methods import *


class ScheduleWindow:
    #All the design of the GUI window takes place here. The GUI adapts to the database table that will be manipulated
    def __init__(self, window, column_names,table_name):
        
        #Window properties
        self.window = window
        self.window.title(f"{table_name} MANIPULATION")
        self.window.geometry("1000x1050")
        self.window.configure(bg="blue")
        self.column_names = column_names
        self.table_name = table_name
        
        # Frame container(s)
        frame = LabelFrame(self.window, text= f"Insert a {table_name}")
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, pady=20)

        # Inputs creation
        self.entries = {}
        for index, column_name in enumerate(self.column_names):
            Label(frame, text=f"{column_name}: ").grid(row=index + 1, column=0)
            entry = Entry(frame)
            entry.grid(row=index + 1, column=1)
            self.entries[column_name] = entry

        # Button creation
        ttk.Button(frame, text=f'Save new {table_name}', command= self.insert_row).grid(row=len(self.column_names) + 1, column = 0, sticky=W + E)
        ttk.Button(frame, text=f'Delete {table_name}', command= self.delete_row).grid(row=len(self.column_names) + 1, column = 1, sticky=W + E)
        ttk.Button(frame, text=f'Update {table_name}', command = self.update_row).grid(row=len(self.column_names) + 1, column=2, sticky=W + E)

        # Control messages
        self.message = Label(text='', fg="red")
        self.message.grid(row=len(self.column_names) + 2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W + E)

        # Display table parameters
        columns = [f"c{i}" for i in range(len(self.column_names))]
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(column=tuple(columns), show='headings', height=8)
        self.tree.grid(row=len(self.column_names) + 3, column=0, columnspan=2)
        
        for index, column_name in enumerate(self.column_names):
            self.tree.column(f"# {index + 1}", anchor=CENTER)
            self.tree.heading(f"# {index + 1}", text=column_name)
        
        #Display information on created table
        self.get_rows()

ScheduleWindow.run_query = run_query
ScheduleWindow.validating_inputs = validating_inputs
ScheduleWindow.get_rows = get_rows
ScheduleWindow.insert_row = insert_row
ScheduleWindow.delete_row = delete_row
ScheduleWindow.update_row = update_row
ScheduleWindow.edit_row = edit_row   

        

class MenuWindow:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.window = window
        self.window.configure(bg="green")
        self.window.title("Menu")
        self.window.geometry("300x300")

        self.create_menu_buttons()

    def create_menu_buttons(self):
        for idx, table in enumerate(get_tables()):
            table_button = ttk.Button(self.window, text=table,
                                      command=lambda t=table: self.open_table(t))
            table_button.grid(row=idx, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W+E)

    def open_table(self, table_name):
        table_window = Toplevel(self.window)
        table_window.config(bg="black")
        column_names = get_column_names(table_name)
        ScheduleWindow( table_window, column_names, table_name)


    
if __name__ == "__main__":

    def get_column_names(table_name):
        with sqlite3.connect("schedule_manager.db") as connection:
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute(f"PRAGMA table_info({table_name})")
            columns_info = cursor.fetchall()
            column_names = [column_info[1] for column_info in columns_info]
        return column_names

    def get_tables():
        with sqlite3.connect("schedule_manager.db") as connection:
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';")
            tables = cursor.fetchall()
        return [table[0] for table in tables]
 
#MAIN TO RUN THROUGH MENU (STILL BUGGING because table doesnt show up on new window)
    
    window = Tk()
    app = MenuWindow(window)
    window.mainloop()
    

#MAIN TO RUN THROUGH EACH TABLE (works better)
'''
    root = Tk()
    TABLE = "Classroom"
    column_names = get_column_names(TABLE)
    app = ScheduleWindow(root, column_names,TABLE)
    root.mainloop()
    '''
```

The second main is for running each window independently and it works. But when opening through the menu it keeps bugging. This other method updates the table when changes are executed, but I don't think it might be related.

```
#updating the visual table (R in CRUD)
def get_rows(self):
    #Clear the zone before displaying
    records = self.tree.get_children()
    for element in records:
        self.tree.delete(element)

    query = f"Select * from {self.table_name}"
    db_rows = self.run_query(query)

    for row in db_rows:
        self.tree.insert('', 0, text=row[1], values=row)
```

Comment: You didn't specify the parent of the treeview `self.tree` (also label `self.message`), so it is created as a child of the root window instead.